# What is the difference between Retrieve vs QueryFrame, EmguCV

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

**Hi, I'm using EmguCV 3.1 for C# and I'd like to know where is the difference between [Capture.Retrieve](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/1b8e2536-14cd-678d-197d-e0a4533a82b4.htm) and [Capture.QueryFrame](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/8dfb0679-4c54-4f17-37ba-7218cbd28e67.htm)?** And why are there two methods to get the same image (since emgu is only a wrapper for opencv and in opencv VideoCapture has only retrieve to get the image (read is a combination of grab + retrieve and >> is read in other notation))

I've tried to find a difference using `Capture.ImageGrabbed` event and a own thread with `Capture.Grab` + `Capture.Retrieve` / Capture.QueryFrame in following combinations but it seems there is no difference at all. Same framerate, size, color depth..

- ImageGrabbed: Retrieve(mat,0) results in a colored image
- ImageGrabbed: Retrieve(mat,1) results in a colored image, too
- ImageGrabbed: QueryFrame results in a StackOverflowException (for whatever reason)
- Thread: Grab + Retrieve results in a colored image
- Thread: QueryFrame results in a colored image

But no difference seen yet. Anyone an idea?